# SQL MS access count more than columes with three where

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have problem with type SQL statement I have more than columns, row and I need to use where and count, I would get result like this but I don't know how can write SQL statement.

```
name|total| ER | OPD | IPD
WBC | 5   |  2 |  3  |  0
PLT | 3   |  1 |  0  |  2
MCV | 7   |  4 |  2  |  1



    SELECT count(WBC) as total,
    (select COUNT(WBC) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER')  as ER,
    (SELECT COUNT(WBC) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD') as OPD,
   (SELECT COUNT(WBC) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD') as IPD 
   FROM Table2 ;
```

second row

```
    SELECT count(PLT) as total,
    (select COUNT(PLT) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER')  as ER,
    (SELECT COUNT(PLT) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD') as OPD,
   (SELECT COUNT(PLT) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD') as IPD 
   FROM Table2 ;
```

and third row

```
    SELECT count(MCV) as total,
    (select COUNT(MCV) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER')  as ER,
    (SELECT COUNT(MCV) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD') as OPD,
   (SELECT COUNT(MCV) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD') as IPD 
   FROM Table2 ;
```

Comment: Hello. You colud use `UNION ALL` statement. Need help with that?

Comment: I didn't see the ms-access tag at the time I answered.

Comment: UNION ALL thank you so much its work well but without name column.

Comment: @Masha2008 in my answer I added name column. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, total, ER, OPD, IPD 
FROM(
    SELECT 1 as order, 'WBC' as name, count(WBC) as total,
    (select COUNT(WBC) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER')  as ER,
    (SELECT COUNT(WBC) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD') as OPD,
    (SELECT COUNT(WBC) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD') as IPD 
    FROM Table2 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2, 'PLT', count(PLT) as total,
    (select COUNT(PLT) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER')  as ER,
    (SELECT COUNT(PLT) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD') as OPD,
    (SELECT COUNT(PLT) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD') as IPD 
    FROM Table2 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 3, 'MCV', count(MCV) as total,
    (select COUNT(MCV) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='ER')  as ER,
    (SELECT COUNT(MCV) FROM Table2 WHERE Section='OPD') as OPD,
    (SELECT COUNT(MCV) FROM Table2 WHERE Section = 'IPD') as IPD 
    FROM Table2
) u
ORDER BY u.order
```

Comment: @Masha2008 try this. If it works for you, you can formaly accept it, see how: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: there are just one column MCV also I try to add HGB by the same way but It still two row.

Comment: @Masha2008 add data sample to your question description. Order by cant be uses within a `View` unless use `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT`.